# How to change kube-proxy config?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

I've tried to change kube-proxy configMap and kube-proxy command to set `metricsBindAddress` but kubernetes resets these changes(without any warnings) after couple seconds.

1. `kubectl edit cm kube-proxy-config -n kube-system` => add `metricsBindAddress` => wait couple seconds and open the config - there is empty metricsBindAddress
2. `kubectl edit ds kube-proxy -n kube-system` => add `--metrics-bind-address` to command => wait couple seconds => the command was reset to default

How to change kube-proxy config and keep these changes ?

Kubernetes version 1.17

UPDATE(as you can, after several seconds metricsBindAddress was changed to empty string):
[image]

UPDATE 2(pay attention on metricsBinAddress, it's changed after ~40-50 seconds):
[image]

**FINAL UPDATE**:
Answer from cloud provider(Yandex) - `kube-proxy pod it is on the host's network, so to prevent security problems, it listens exclusively on the loopback address and therefore the parameter will be reset`

p.s. https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator#kubeproxy - I want to make kube-proxy accessible by prometheus

Comment: I am using version 1.18 and editing the metricsBindAddress is working fine.

Comment: @AlifBiswas my collegue also try and he has the same problem. can you change metricsBindAddress, wait couple seconds and try to change again? in my and collegue case it show `""` instead of the address I set

Comment: Still showing the same. By the way, The helm chart you  mentioned in the post is deprecated. Are you sure this is not causing any problem?

Comment: @AlifBiswas no, I don't think the deprecated chart can reset kube-proxy config. Maybe it's my cloud provider..  
Thank you

Comment: What exactly version are you using on your cluster? I tried on `v1.17.17` and have only `kube-proxy` configmap and you are editing configmap named `kube-proxy-config`. What environment you are using, its local or cloud env? Are you using some specific configuration or it's fresh cluster and you just wanted to edit `kube-proxy` configmap?

Comment: @PjoterS `Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.12", GitCommit:"5ec472285121eb6c451e515bc0a7201413872fa3", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-16T13:32:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`   
 | 
`Depending on the cluster, the relevant part config.conf will be in ConfigMap kube-system/kube-proxy or kube-system/kube-proxy-config` (c) https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator#kubeproxy   

Cloud environment, it's fresh cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting this `Community Wiki` because root cause of the issue has been determined.

Usually to change of `metricsBindAddress:` can be achieved by editing [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) and `delete kube-proxy pod` or use `rollout restart` on `DaemonSet`.

Root cause of this issue was that this change was blocked by OP's environment - [Yandex Cloud](https://cloud.yandex.com/).

OP received feedback from `Yandex Support`

> kube-proxy pod it is on the host's network, so to prevent security problems, it listens exclusively on the loopback address and therefore the parameter will be reset

Answer (score 5):

First edit:

```
kubectl edit cm/kube-proxy -n kube-system

.....
metricsBindAddress: 0.0.0.0:10249
.....
```

Then,

```
kubectl rollout restart ds kube-proxy -n kube-system
```

You have to restart the pods otherwise they do not get the configuration.
You can check the status by:

```
kubectl rollout status ds kube-proxy -n kube-system
```

Comment: I did it several times , but metricsBindAddress resets. I've updated first post, you can see what am I talking about